# ng-pattern is not working for specific email address?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I want to validate specific domain email validation using `ng-pattern` , lets say i want this pattern `ab123z@domain.com` or `ab1234@domain.com` these are two condition i have to apply when user have input values. I tried below `emailFromat` but it shows invalid in all scenarios ? any better approach ?

main.html

```
<div layout="row">
    <md-input-container flex="100">
        <label>Cc</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="notifyCtrl.cc" ng-list="," ng-pattern="pattern(user.type)">
        <div class="help-block" ng-messages="notifyForm.email.$error" ng-show="notifyForm.email.$touched && notifyForm.email.$invalid">
            <div ng-if="user.type === 'notify'">
                <div ng-message="pattern">
                    An email name must only contain a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or _ characters.(ie. ab123c@tad.com, ab1234@tad.com
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </md-input-container>
</div>
```

ctrl.js

```
var emailFormat = "/^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]+@+(?: |[a-z0-9-]+\.com|com|[a-z0-9-])$/" 

$scope.pattern = function(type){ 
    if(type === 'notify') {
        return emailFormat; 
    }  
};
```

Comment: why its being down voted ? can i get some comment as well .

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes from the regex. There is no need for it. https://regex101.com/r/njkXrr/1

```
var emailFormat = /^[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]*[a-zA-Z]{2}@+(?: |[a-z0-9-]+\.com|com|[a-z0-9-])$/

$scope.pattern = function(type){ 
    if(type === 'notify') {
        return emailFormat; 
    }  
};
```

Comment: that `/` wasn't meant to be an escape, it was meant to be a literal match (which works, btw).  However, this regex is still broken;  it will match for a single character after the `@`. (i.e. `abc123@a`).  https://regex101.com/r/KcIbq3/1/

Comment: how can make it specific to domain like ab123z@domain.com ?

Comment: @Claies Thanks mate. Updated the answer

Comment: @hussain Updated the answer for that. Check now

Comment: email character pattern has to be these two `ab123z@domain.com` or `ab1234@domain.com` as i mentioned in question , is it doable ?

Comment: both the above email match the provided regex. Can you provide an email which should not match so that i get clear understanding

Comment: these are invalid `abc23c@domain.com` `a234hj@domain.com`` s3123k@domain.com` first two  must be alphabet and in other case first two and last should be aplhabet

Comment: another thing i noticed i am using ng-list its breaking that functionality i should have option to add multiple email address with comma

Comment: This should do: /^[a-zA-Z]{2}[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]*[a-zA-Z]{2}@+(?: |[a-z0-9-]+\.com|com|[a-z0-9-])$/

Comment: @hussain With gagan's input, i believe it will work correctly

Comment: @AgamBanga with gagans i tried neither of case i mentioned is working. so your solution worked well only when i add comma to separate another email it breaks